# CONTAINSTABLE function not returning RANK in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 identical database in SQL Server 2005 and 2012, they have the same full-text index setting. But when I executed `CONTAINSTABLE`, I got very different result.

```
select max(rank) FROM CONTAINSTABLE(Candidate, (RawCopyPasteResume), 'SQL')
```

When I execute the above query in SQL Server 2005, I'm getting 12 as `RANK` value. But when I execute same in SQL Server 2012, I'm getting `null` as `RANK`. Link this, I'm getting different results for different search keywords..

Due to this, I couldn't able to get the result I'm expecting. What might be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried running `DBCC CHECKDB WITH DATA_PURITY`. Did you set the compatibility level of your DB to SQL Server 2012: `ALTER DATABASE <database_name> SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL=110;`? Did you rebuild the `INDEX`?

Comment: Might be silly question, but did you tested that number of rows returned is same for both versions? Replace max(rank) with * and post restults.

Comment: @TT. yes I checked DATA_PURITY.no error.. Set compatibility level too. But still same result.

Comment: @PatrikTřeštík, I replaced max(rank) with *. In Server 2005 it return 45 rows. In Server 2012, it return only 3 rows.

Comment: Based on different number of rows, there must be some difference in data. CONTAINS works purely on fulltext index so there could be problem with index itself.   Check result differences and lookup rows by KEY returned.